# Registry ACL using .NET GetAccessControl() output flood

Tags: .net, powershell, output, registry

I'm currently helping a colleague making a script that images all ACL settings in the registry, so I made some code that loops through the registry with several threads and builds a report in CSV.

This is pretty straightforward. There's a lot of keys in the registry so I have extensively tested every cmdlet and .NET method for execution times and, based on those results, came to mostly use .NET to make it as efficient as possible. In the context of this particular question: I perform `Get-Item` on every indexed key and call `.GetAccessControl()` on them.

This works fine, but two keys in specific are giving me a headache:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\*\ 
 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\*\shell`

Why, you may ask? Well, look at this:

```
PS C:\Users\StackOverflow> (gi HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\*\).GetAccessControl().Count
4124
PS C:\Users\StackOverflow> (gi HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\*\shell).GetAccessControl().Count
175
```

That's a lot of items for an ACL!

I'm using StreamWriter to write my own CSV, this too works just fine until it hits these two keys. When the file is opened in a text editor the contents are as predicted, but Microsoft Excel completely breaks while trying to read this.

I have no clue why this happens, when I open these keys in regedit there doesn't seem to be nearly as many access definitions as powershell is returning here. Can anyone clarify this?

Comment: post the code too on how you are fetching, parsing and appending it to csv

Comment: I can't post the entire source, company policy. The relevant parts are up here. You can reproduce the behavior in question with the code in my question. For example, `(gi HKLM:\SOFTWARE\).GetAccessControl()` will yield a few results. But when you perform the same on the two keys I mentioned in my question, it goes whack.

Comment: this part is clear. Show how you are appending the data in the csv file. What are the headers mainly you are considering. Atleast a sample should work.

Comment: Each thread obtains (or waits for) a mutex and writes the output to the csv file via StreamWriter: `$Output.GetEnumerator() | % { $stream.WriteLine("`"$($_.Key)`";`"$($_.Value)`"") }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was as straightforward as the question apparently. Using `-LiteralPath` for `Get-Item` will solve this since the paths contained wildcard characters.

Comment: Yep. This would be status by design. Glad you got it sorted out.